# How to debug bookmark anchors not working because of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, joomla, anchor, conflict, bookmarks

I came into an issue where I thought all of my links containing anchor bookmarks (ie: "/index.php#top") were not working with FireFox.  I came to the conclusion that there is some JavaScript within the Joomla 2.5 template I am developing that is killing off all of my links within my pages that contain hash marks (making them not go anywhere).

To see what I am talking about, here is my template that is working correctly:
http://www.lawsonsp.com/ink-information/textile-plastisol-inks?jtpl=8

and here is my template containing the issue:
http://www.lawsonsp.com/ink-information/textile-plastisol-inks?jtpl=9

On this page (on both templates) the image links at the top of the main content should link down to their corresponding sections below (ie: "#white")

How do I go about diagnosing WHICH Javascript code is killing the links containing hash marks? (preferably with FireFox, but with any method would be appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to tackle this exact problem.  I found using jQuery to listen for and manage the event was the most effective solution.  Here is a sample of the code I used:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

jQuery(document).on('click', '#go-to-my-anchor', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = '#my-anchor';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @user3295190, but I feel that I am too unfamiliar with JS coding that I'm not even sure where to put this code to implement...

Answer (score 0):

I found that, in the lower section of the jqm.init.js file, some settings are initialized and/or deactivated before JQuery mobile is loaded.  A couple of these lines are commented out by default, and I found two that correspond to handling links with a hash like in my issue.

I've made sure the following lines are uncommented to allow normal link handling by the browser instead of JQuery (I'm pretty sure)

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
   ...
   $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
   $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
   ...
});
```

If anyone sees a problem with this, please let me know as I am admittedly new to JS coding...